# Проблема в моей логике PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Смотрите , у нас есть ключ , который мы покупаем на месяц , и есть программа , которая проверяет , если

```
$a = $ee["adate"]+1-1;
    $aa = $Date - $a;
    if ($ee["active"] == 0) {
    mysqli_query($mysql_con, "UPDATE `DN` SET active = '1' , IP = '$ipaddress', ActDate = '$Date' WHERE `kkey` = '$key'");
    echo json_encode("1");
    }
    else {
        if ($aa < 30) {
        mysqli_query($mysql_con, "UPDATE `DN` SET active = '1' , IP = '$ipaddress', ActDate = '$Date' WHERE `kkey` = '$key'");
echo json_encode("1");
    }
    else {
    echo json_encode("2");
    }
    }
```

adate - дата покупки 
То есть , мы из сегодняшний даты вычитаем дату покупки , и если эта дата меньше 30 тогда говорит 1 , а если нет , то 2 , а вся прелесть в том , что если наступит новый месяц ? Тогда всё поломается ! Помогите сделать так , что бы проверялся еще и месяц , и сделать , что бы всё было корректно , помогите пожалуйста !

Comment: `$a = $ee["adate"]+1-1;` <= неплохо!

Answer (score 2):

Логика сложна у вас. Судя по всему вам нужно возвращать значение 1, если период активации, который составляет 30 дней с момента активации, еще не закончился и ключ не активирован ранее, и 2, если уже вышел срок.
Если я вас правильно понял, то вот попробуйте так (код не проверял в работе, написал на коленке...)

```
// Проверяем если ключ не активирован
// если прошло меньше 30 дней
// и ищем по ключу
$result = mysql_query($mysql_con, 'SELECT * FROM `DN` WHERE `kkey`="' . $key . '" AND ActDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND `active` = 0');
if ($result) {
    // Если нашли не активированный ключ 
    mysqli_query($mysql_con, "UPDATE `DN` SET active = '1' , IP = '$ipaddress', ActDate = '$Date' WHERE `kkey` = '$key'");
    echo json_encode('1');
} else {
    echo json_encode('2');
}
```

Или же если нужно условие на проверку даты, которая должна укладываться относительно заданной на -30 дней, то в первый запрос и условие поставь такое:

```
$result = mysql_query($mysql_con, 'SELECT "' . $Date . '" < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY');
if ($result) {
```

Comment: Вот такая вот штука у меня в 12 лет ... Логика такая себе ) Но пытаюсь ) Спасибо за ответ !

Comment: Молодец! ) Удачи!

Comment: А в случае если более 30 дней , то выведет NULL ? 
    SELECT "' . $Date . '" < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY

Comment: Да, т.е. условие if не сработает